# Yii editMe WYSIWYG wont save edits.

Tags: php, wysiwyg, yii

I am using the Yii editMe Extension in one of my forms. The WYSIWYG editor populates perfectly fine and works fine however when you save none of the changes are saved.

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'content-form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'content_title'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'content_title',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>80)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'content_title'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'content_text'); ?>
    <?php $this->widget('ext.editMe.ExtEditMe', array(
                'model'=>$model,
                'attribute'=>'content_text',
                ));?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'content_text'); ?>

</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

That is the code for my form page.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, so I did a little digging. The widget should be inserted in a `<form>`...`</form>` whose action attribute is set. No submit button required. The extension's own save button gets activated by this change and works seamlessly.